# fill out a webform that uses javascript with python

Tags: webforms, python-3.3

i am trying to fill out a webform using a python program by submitting specific values. the problem is it uses javascript. i will post an example of the value i want to fill.

```
fo.addVariable("email","email@yahoo.com")
fo.addVariable("age","19")
fo.addVariable("gender","M")
fo.addVariable("line","hello")
```

that is an example of the value on the page. what i want to do is submit a value to that and change it. what i am currently attempting is this:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"line": "hello", "age": "50", "email":  "email@yahoo.com", "gender": "M"}).encode()
resp = urlreq.urlopen("http://url.com/update", data)
```

this usually works for most webforms. but for this one it will not.

Comment: First things first: Java is something completely different from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, urllib has no attribute urllib.parse and a .encode() function  at the end is unnecessary.

I think what you should be writing is

```
data = urllib.urlencode({"line": "hello", "age": "50", "email":  "email@yahoo.com", "gender": "M"})
```

Comment: im using python 3.3. plus none of the values are submitting.

Comment: and that is proper syntax for python 3.3